# puppeteer page.evaluate path vs test-ID

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, screen-scraping, end-to-end, puppeteer

Im trying get the value from a div in puppeteer e2e tests. The pice of html and js looks a bit like this. The problem is the results. When I run this code with the id's its result is literally ' ' just a empty line in the console.

However if I swap `},'[data-testid="TestID10"]')` with the commented line of code I get the right response 'Hello World' in the console. (note: using Full html selector path's is not a good practice when working with puppeteer)

Can anyone tell me why this won't work with ID's? and how I can get around this since using HTML selectors is really a bad practice.

Kind regards!

```js
const value1 = await page
        .waitForSelector('[data-testid="TestID10"]')
        .then(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(
                page.evaluate((path) => {
                    return window.document
                        .querySelector(path)
                        .value;
                },'[data-testid="TestID10"]')
            )
        });
    console.log(value1);
    
    //  },'#0-row-0 > div > div.TableCell.row-0.col-0.TextInputCell > div')
```

```html
<div class="TextInputCell" data-testid="TestID10">
  <span class="value">Hello Word</span>
</div
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The follwing works fine for me. Notice I put the `selector` into a `variable` rather than using a string. Also I am returning the `innerText` not `value` as in your example. HTH

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() { 

const htmlStr = '<!doctype html><html><head></head>' +
  '<body><div class="TextInputCell" data-testid="TestID10">' +
  '<span class="value">Hello Word</span></div></body></html>';

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(htmlStr);    

  const selector = '[data-testid="TestID10"]';
  await page.waitForSelector(selector);

  var innerText = await page.evaluate((sel) => {
        return document.querySelector(sel).innerText;
  }, selector);

  console.log(innerText);

  browser.close();

};

run();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for notifying me. Seems like my code worked aswell but when I was implementing your piece of code I noticed there was an empty input field above the div. Somehow this input field had exactly the same data-testid assinged to it. That caused the empty line in my console. 

Thanks a lot for helping me out so quickly!